# Difference between "came to" and "came up to"

Tags: phrase-usage

For these expression which of these two **came to/came up to** should I use

> In the morning he **came** / **came up** to me and said that.......
>
> I forgot my phone in the cafetaria in the afternoon.  I realized that when I **came** / **came up** to the elevator.

Can anyone please explain the difference between *came to* vs. *came up to*?

Comment: In both the examples, I would use a different verb: _reached me_ in the first case, and _was in the elevator_ in the second case.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think I'd say "In the morning he reached me and said that...".  (If this sentence is possible, I'd interpret it as "reaching" me on a phone.)  I would say "I realized that when I was in the elevator", but it doesn't mean the same thing as the OP's example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that *came up to* means roughly the same as *approached* (that is, *move into close proximity with*):

> She came **up** to the window and asked to buy four tickets.

whereas *came to* can be used to mean *arrive at*:

> I remember the day the veterinarian came to our farm and brought the bad news.

Obviously, there is some overlap between the two, because when you move close to something, you are also arriving there. Because of that, I would say that you could **always** use *came to*, but you wouldn't necessarily always be able to always use *came up to* without a possible slight shift in meaning. For example, in my second sentence, if I were to say:

> I remember the day the veterinarian came **up** to our farm and brought the bad news.

that might imply something different. It could imply the doctor walked up along the road and stood at the fence (as opposed to in the original sentence, where it's easier for me to imagine the veterinarian in the kitchen). Another possible interpretation after adding the word *up* is that the veterinarian came from further away – in other words: *I remember when the veterinarian came up [from the city] to bring us the bad news*.

However, if I said:

> She came to the window and asked to buy four tickets.

that pretty much says the same as the original, because we *approach* a ticket counter in the same way we *arrive at* a ticket counter.

As a footnote, these usages don't include more idiomatic uses of *came to*, such as:

> - I heard the trivia question on television, but it wasn't until I was driving in my car an hour later that the answer *came to* me.
> - The boxer was unconscious on the mat for a few seconds before he *came to*.

Answer (score 11):

*Came up to* means *approached* or *walked up to*; it is used in contexts where one person is stationary (sitting or standing) and another person, **on foot,** approaches, comes up to or walks up to them.  This expression would be appropriate for your first example.  I disagree with kiamlaluno: *reached me* would not be a suitable synonym here, at least not in North American English.

Neither *came to* nor *came up to* is the best choice for your second example; neither is kimalaluno's suggestion (*was in*).  The best verb phrase is *got to the elevator,* or, more formally, *arrived at the elevator.*  Both of these show that you had arrived at the elevator but had not entered it yet, whereas kiamlaluno's rephrase means that you were already inside the elevator when you made the realization.  Both *came to* and *came up to* are unnatural because, at least in the short text provided, there is no implication of *here* that would require the use of *come*.  However, I would also suggest that kiamlaluno`s mistaken suggestion for the first example sentence would be an appropriate replacement verb phrase here: *reached the elevator*.

Comment: I agree with every word here except ***made** the realisation*. Like [most people](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+the+realisation%2Cmade+the+realization%2Ccame+to+the+realization%2Ccame+to+the+realisation&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), I would say ***came to** the realisation*.

Answer (score 3):

*come up to* means walk really close to the object and stand next to it. *Come to* is a generic synonym to *arrived at location*.

> He came to my house

that means he went inside, maybe visited me, or maybe talked with my neighbors, or maybe hung around making photos.

> He came up to my house

That means he stood next to the wall. Say, he wanted to check the paint on the wall, or read the address plate. He definitely didn't enter the house, just stood outside, next to it.

In most context the two will be synonymous, you come to a person when you come up to them - that's two different phrasings of the same action, with slightly different connotations (you come to a friend, you come up to someone you want to punch them) but in some contexts they will be different - "coming to" will mean getting there for practical purposes, be it visiting, talking, using, shopping. Coming up to means stopping next to it.