# 'Come to'/'Come in': what is the difference?

Tags: phrase-usage

Consider these expressions:

> *Come to* my room.
>
> *Come in* my room.

> When I *came in* the lobby/corridor in the evening, there were tons of people gathered around for X.
>
> When I *came to* the lobby/corridor in the evening, there were tons of people gathered around for X.

Can anyone explain to me whether there is any difference between *come in*  and *come to* in this context? Because of my native language, I tend to use *come in* rather than *come to*.

Comment: similar, but not identical: [Difference between “came to” and “came up to”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3071/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For different circumstances you would use different forms.  Here are some instances.

• “Come to my room”: While away from your room, you tell a person to come with you to your room; or via telephone, tell someone to come to your room.

• “Come in my room”: Standing outside the door of your room talking with someone, you ask them to come in to continue a discussion.  But typically it would be stated more briefly or at least differently: “Come in”, “Come on in, let's sit down”, etc without mentioning the room, since it is right there anyway.  Note, *into* is a likely prospect when the room is mentioned.

• “When I came in the lobby in the evening, there were tons of people gathered around...”: This form is inappropriate; use *[into](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/into#Preposition)* instead.  I'd use *into* for going into a lobby from inside a hotel.

• “When I came to the lobby in the evening, there were tons of people gathered around...”:  I'd use *to* for going to a lobby in a hotel, from elsewhere, but typically no real distinction will be made between use of  *to* and *into* in this context.

• “When I came to in the lobby in the evening, there were tons of people gathered around...”: This form is appropriate if you passed out and are regaining consciousness.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding of the difference in the two prepositions, "in" and "to": 
In the room = being inside the room; to enter the room. To the room = being in the proximity of the room, but not necessarily inside it. Come to my room might mean to come and knock on the door, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Come to** is equivalent to *approach* or *arrive at*.

**Come in** (or *come into* or *come in to*) is equivalent to *enter*.